# When to call API in React and when to call API in Redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

Simply,

**I just wanted to Know when should I call the API in redux actions using redux-thunk and when should I directly call it in react Component (in Constructor or ComponentDidMount ),**

It would be really helpful to know which to use when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use Redux**

When you want your API Response to be used across multiple parts of your application .

**Use ComponentDidMount**

when the API response is specific only to that component and its not needed to be shared across the application .

Comment: That's a pretty good rule of thumb.  I am often unsure of what to fetch in Redux vs in React because with hooks it's possible to create a hook for the API fetch which can be used in many components.